# How can I open a download popup for all kind of files in my Perl CGl script?

Tags: perl, attachment

On my application, the user needs to click on a file name, and then the user is supposed to choose either to download the file or open it. I put code for it that is working fine for .doc, .txt extentions yet it is not working fine for .docx

My code is the following:

```
 @header('Location:'.$attachment_path);
```

Any idea of how to do it so it will work for all kind of attachment?

Comment: have you added the valid Content-Type?

Comment: That doesn't look like real Perl.

Comment: Yes right, that was php, sorry. Yet I found a fix on perl. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks I found out a solution.

`print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";`

`print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";`

Comment: Second line only. Keep the real content-type, not a made up one.